# Discrete functions as functions of value of another function

Tags: co.combinatorics

Consider the set of all discrete functions from $\mathbb F_q^2$ to $\mathbb F_q$ (denote it by $\mathcal F(\mathbb F_q^2, \mathbb F_q)$, the cardinality $|\mathcal F(\mathbb F_q^2, \mathbb F_q)| = q^{q^2}$). Some of the functions can be computed just from the *value* of others, i.e.
$$
f(x,y) = \phi_{f,g} (g(x,y)),
$$
where $\phi_{f,g} : \mathbb F_q \to \mathbb F_q$ in general depends on $f$ and $g$.

Some particular examples:

- shift by a constant ($a \in \mathbb F_q$): $f(x,y) = g(x,y) + a$
- multiplication by a constant: $f(x,y) = a \cdot g(x,y)$
- raising to a power $t < q$: $f(x,y) = (g(x,y))^t$. If $t \geq q$ we can reduce it, as $a^q = a$ for any $a \in \mathbb F_q$ and therefore $(g(x,y))^{t} = (g(x,y))^{t-q+1}$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb F_q$.
- and others.

I want to build the minimum subset $\mathcal G \subset \mathcal F(\mathbb F_q^2, \mathbb F_q)$ such that every function in $\mathcal F(\mathbb F_q^2, \mathbb F_q)$ can be calculated from one function from $\mathcal G$. In other words, for each $f \in \mathcal F(\mathbb F_q^2,\, \mathbb F_q)$ there exist $g = g_f \in \mathcal G$ and $\phi = \phi_{f,g_f} : \mathbb F_q \to \mathbb F_q$ such that
$$
f(x, y) = \phi (g(x,y)), \quad \forall x,y \in \mathbb F_q.
$$

What could such subset $\mathcal G$ be? Or, at least, what could its cardinality be?

P.S. What are possible generalisations to the case of $k$-ary functions, i.e. $f : \mathbb F_q^k \to \mathbb F_q$?

Comment: Sorry for the poor phrasing in the question title. I can't come up with something better.

Comment: You seek the smallest $m$ where $*_1,\ldots,*_m$ are binary operations on $\mathbb{F}_q$ and for any binary operation $*$ on $\mathbb{F}_q$, there exists a unary operation $u:\mathbb{F}_q \rightarrow \mathbb{F}_q$ and $i$ such that $a * b = u(a *_i b)$ for all $a,b \in \mathbb{F}_q$. Is this correct or an oversimplification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is essentially counting the number of partitions of a set of $q^2$ labelled elements into $q$ unlabelled groups. (This generalizes to counting surjective maps from one labelled set onto a smaller set.) This is because you only ask for a "rewriting of the output" by a unary function on the range set.  I believe the Twelvefold Way (in the context of Enumerative Combinatorics) includes this case as a way of enumerating such maps.

A more general situation than the one described is where one is allowed to permute the inputs, either by individual functions on each variable or by switching the variables, or both. The exact enumeration of this is more challenging, but usually dividing by the size of the suggested automorphism group generated by the input transformations leads to a correct or at least target asymptotic for the number of representatives of the class you seek.

Gerhard "This Is Candidate For Migration" Paseman, 2019.03.26.